# break up key value pairs into separate objects with the same keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm sorry if this is redundant with other posts but I currently have the following array:

```
let test = {1:100, 2:200, 3:300}
```

But I'd like to convert this to:

```
test = [
{id: 1, value: 100},
{id: 2, value: 200},
{id: 3, value: 300}
]
```

Any help appreciated - even just pointing me to posts that solve this question :)

Comment: That definitely gets me closer, but I'd like to the objects to have the names "id" and "value" whereas that just creates array pairs - I'll try using that as a start!

Comment: If you’re looking for the inverse of this: [How do I convert array of Objects into one Object in JavaScript?](/q/19874555/4642212).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get an array of key, value pairs and then map that to an array of objects:

```js
let test = {1:100, 2:200, 3:300};

let out = Object.entries(test).map(([k, v]) => ({ id : k, value: v }));
console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version using `keys` and `map`:

```js
var obj = {1:100,2:200,3:300}
var result = Object.keys(obj).map((key) => ({ id: key, value: obj[key]}));

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Object.entries() and some destructuring

```js
let test = {1:100, 2:200, 3:300}
let res = Object.entries(test).map(([id, value]) => ({id, value}))
   


console.log(res)
```